# How to update a jsonb column with a replaced value in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL table called `files` which includes a jsonb table called `formats`. While some rows are `[null]`, others have objects with this structure:

```json
{
  "thumbnail": {
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "url": "https://some-url.com/image01.jpg",
    "name": "image01.jpg",
    //...other properties
  }
}
```

For every row I want to update the `thumbnail.url` and replace `some-url` with `other-url`.

I'm far from being an expert in PostgreSQL (or any other DB for that matter), and after some reading I tried to run the following query in pgAdmin:

```sql
UPDATE files 
  SET formats = jsonb_set(formats, '{thumbnail.url}', REPLACE('{thumbnail.url}', 'some-url', 'other-url'))
```

And I received this error: `function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text) does not exist`

I tried to set format `jsonb_set(formats::jsonb...)`, tried to target `'{thumbnail}'` instead of `'{thumbnail.url}'` - always the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Or is pgAdmin really doesn't support this function? How can I do such an update with pgAdmin query tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to use `->>` to get JSON content value of `url` and then replace your expect value from that.

Because your `url` field of your JSON might be string type we need to use `"` to content it before cast as `JSONB`

> jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])

```
UPDATE files 
SET formats = jsonb_set(formats, '{thumbnail,url}', CONCAT('"',REPLACE(formats->'thumbnail'->>'url','some-url','other-url'),'"')::JSONB);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5e08258ab4dfe2c3f278a595ca266234)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really wasn't aware of such intricacies of this. And special thanks for the dbfiddle link, I didn't know such website exists! And I was looking for something like that!

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `jsonb_set()` must be an array with one array element for each "path" element. So the second parameter should be `'{thumbnail,url}'` or more obvious: `array['thumbnail', 'url']`

And the third parameter must be a `jsonb` value, but `replace` returns a `text`, so you need to use e.g. `to_jsonb()` to convert the result of the `replace()` to a jsonb value.

And as D-Shih pointed out, you need to extract the old value using `->>`. But to get the URL you need to "navigate" to it: `formats -> 'thumbnail ->> 'url'`

I would also add a WHERE clause so that you only update rows that actually contain a URL.

```sql
UPDATE files 
  SET formats = jsonb_set(formats, 
                          '{thumbnail,url}', 
                          to_jsonb(replace(formats -> 'thumbnail' ->> 'url', 'some-url', 'other-url'))
                          )
where (formats -> 'thumbnail') ? 'url'
```